# How to pass an BIG5 chinese characters in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I want to pass an Chinese characters (BIG5) in NSURLConnection in my request but it shows an error

```
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0xa17a750 {NSUnderlyingError=0xa17ffa0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your string by using `-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` method before using it in URL. And I suspect you should also convert your big5 string to utf8 before escaping.

EDIT:

To use BIG5 you can use this:

```
NSStringEncoding big5 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingBig5);
```

Comment: But i need to change the chinese characters into BIG5 not in UTF8