# How to use Big5 encoding in Swift on iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, encoding, swift3, big5

I'm scanning a QR-Code with chinese characters encoded in Big5. (主页概况)

Is there a chance to get this String decoded correctly in Swift 3?

I found this [Objective-C example](https://gist.github.com/zonble/659647) on GitHub and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715644/how-to-pass-an-big5-chinese-characters-in-objective-c), but there are no `kCFStringEncodingBig5_HKSCS_1999` and `kCFStringEncodingBig` constants in Swift.

---

**Update:**

I found the corresponding swift variables, so i now tried the following:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    guard metadataObjects?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
        return
    }
    guard let metadata = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject, let code = metadata.stringValue else {
        return
    }
    let big5encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))
    print("Big5 encoded String: " + (String(data: code.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)!, encoding: big5encoding) ?? "?"))
}
```

Output: `Big5 encoded String: \326\367\322\263\270\305\277\366`

How can i get to the expected output `Big5 encoded String: 主页概况`

---

**Update 2:**

It seems that my QR-Code contained some corrupt data, so i created a new Code, this time the content is definitely a Big5 encoded String (Android App reads it correctly). The content is `傳統`

When I scan this code with my iOS app, metadata.stringValue returns the japanese String `ｶﾇｲﾎ`

What the hell is going on here???

Comment: Try `UInt(CFStringEncodings.big5_HKSCS_1999.rawValue)`

Comment: What is your actual input data? It seems that you convert a string to data (using nonLossyASCII) and then back to a string (using big5encoding).

Comment: thats correct, I'll add some more code to make it more clear

Comment: What is the value of `code.data`?

Comment: The data in the QR-Code is `主页概况` encoded in Big5.
metadata.stringValue returns a string that looks like this: `Ö÷Ò³¸Å¿ö`.
The value of code.data is `\326\367\322\263\270\305\277\366`

Comment: What does `print(Array(metadata.stringValue.unicodeScalars))`  and `print(metadata.stringValue.data(using: .utf32BigEndian)! as NSData)` show?

Comment: unicodeScalars: ["\u{00D6}", "\u{00F7}", "\u{00D2}", "\u{00B3}", "\u{00B8}", "\u{00C5}", "\u{00BF}", "\u{00F6}"]

Comment: UTF32 Big Endian: <000000d6 000000f7 000000d2 000000b3 000000b8 000000c5 000000bf 000000f6>

Comment: it seems that my QR-Code contained corrupt data... :/

Answer (score 7):

[`CFStringEncodings`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfstringencodings)
are defined as enumeration values in Swift 3:

```
public enum CFStringEncodings : CFIndex {

    // ...    
    case big5 /* Big-5 (has variants) */
    // ...    
    case big5_HKSCS_1999 /* Big-5 with Hong Kong special char set supplement*/
    // ...    
}
```

so you have to convert

```
CFStringEncodings -> CFStringEncoding -> NSStringEncoding -> String.Encoding
```

Example:

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.big5
let nsEnc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
let big5encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: nsEnc) // String.Encoding
```

Then `big5encoding` can be used for conversion between `String` and `(NS)Data`.

In your case you have a string where each unicode scalar corresponds to
a byte of the Big5 encoding. Then the following should work:

```
// let code = "\u{00D6}\u{00F7}\u{00D2}\u{00B3}\u{00B8}\u{00C5}\u{00BF}\u{00F6}"
let bytes = code.unicodeScalars.map { UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: $0.value) }
if let result = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: big5encoding) {
    print(result)
}
```

Alternatively, using the fact that the ISO Latin 1 encoding maps
the Unicode code points U+0000 .. U+00FF to the bytes 0x00 .. 0xFF:

```
if let data = code.data(using: .isoLatin1),
    let result = String(data: data, encoding: big5encoding) {
    print(result)
}
```