# How to encode extended ASCII/macOS Roman (characters from 128 to 255) on 1 byte in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift5

I'm trying to write a `.txt` file with extended ASCII code, but I need to do it on 8-bit characters.

I'd love to get extended ASCII from `Codepage 437`, but I can live with `Mac OS Roman`. But as it's operation on numbers, it shouldn't make any difference.

When using `Character(UnicodeScalar(unicodePosition))`, it works well for 0 to 127. Each character is 8-bit. From 128th scalar up, they are not ASCII/macOS Roman and they're encoded on 16 bits.

So I can create an array of `UInt8` with specific characters that I want to save to file.

```swift
let firstCharacter: UInt8 = 240 // Apple Logo in macOS Roman or "≡" in codepage 437

let secondCharacter: UInt8 = 236 // Infinity symbol on codepage 437 or "I" with two dots in macOS Roman

let listOfCharacters: [UInt8] = [firstCharacter, secondCharacter]
```

But I have no idea on how to save such a list to a file, and then display it as extendedASCII or macOS Roman encoding.

I need to operate on this numbers because I'm trying to implement Vigenre Cipher for extended ASCII alphabet (or macOS Roman) and I need the 8-bit input to be 8-bit output so the content of the file have exactly the same file size. I **have to** do it on 256 characters, hence I need extended ascii/macOS Roman.

I'd also need to read this kind of file back, so method for reading a textile encoded with extended ASCII would also be appreciated. I guess that's why there's `String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII` and not only `.ascii`?

Comment: There's `String.Encoding.macOSRoman`. Why don't you use it?

Comment: Because in Vigenre Cipher I need to operate on numbers. To encrypt letter "a" (97) with key "b" (98) I will `97+98=196` get a symbol `math function` in macOS Roman. But I need to be able to create this character using this number, like this `Character(macOSRomanSymbol(196))`

Comment: Eh, that's irrelevant. You were asking about using encoding to/from strings. There's proper encoding .macOSRoman, use it instead of .ascii/.nonLossyASCII

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) is available as [`CFStringEncodings.dosLatinUS`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfstringencodings/doslatinus) and can be converted to a `String.Encoding` as in [How to use Big5 encoding in Swift on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063591/how-to-use-big5-encoding-in-swift-on-ios/44064027#44064027):

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.dosLatinUS
let nsEnc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: nsEnc) // String.Encoding
```

Now you can convert the bytes to a string and back:

```
let bytes = Data([240, 236])
// CP437 to string:
if let string = String(data: bytes, encoding: encoding) {
    print(string) // ≡∞
    // String to CP437:
    if let bytes2 = string.data(using: encoding) {
        print(Array(bytes2)) // [240, 236]
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW. I think this is it! I'll test it and come back with the results! :)

Comment: That worked well for saving bytes to file. How to load `test.txt` file encoded with 437 to array of `8UInt`? Trying `let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: "/Users/vol/Downloads/test.txt")! as Data`

Comment: @vol: The counterpart to `let string = String(data: bytes, encoding: encoding)` is `let bytes = string.data(using: encoding)`

Comment: @vol: But note that you can read/write `Data` to/from a file without using strings or any encoding, perhaps that is what you actually need?

Comment: Thanks. I need that one because encryption key is a string taken from `TextField`, from GUI. You sir are the best!

Answer (score 3):

The simple approach is to start with a `String` instance, convert it to `Data` using a specified encoding and then convert it the `[UInt8]` array:

```
let text = "The quick brown fox ... éâ..."
let data = text.data(using: .macOSRoman)
let characters [UInt8](data)
```

Be carefule with your encryption. Most characters in the range between 0 and 31 cannot be represented in text. They might not occur in the original text. But they will appear in the encrypted text. If you don't avoid it, the result will be binary data that can no longer be converted to readable text.

Comment: In Vigenre Cipher I need to operate on numbers. To encrypt letter "a" (97) with key "b" (98) I will 97+98=196 get a `symbol math function` in macOS Roman. But I need to be able to create this character using this number, like this Character(macOSRomanSymbol(196)). In your solution I'd need to write the whole mapping from Unicode Numbers to macOS Roman numbers myself.

Comment: @vol: I don't understand where you get your numbers from. You should probably provide more information in your question. Anyway, you don't need to map it yourself. It's done in line 2 of my code. Let's say you start with an array of Unicode codepoints, then you can easily create a string with them and apply my code to get an array of MacOSRoman codes.

Comment: @vol: Or are you in fact looking for the reverse operation: MacOSRoman to Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

So my final solution looks like this:

```swift
class FileManager {

    let encoding: String.Encoding

    init() {
        let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.dosLatinUS
        let nsEnc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
        let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: nsEnc)
        self.encoding = encoding
    }

    func loadFromFile(path: String) -> Data {
        return NSData(contentsOfFile: path)! as Data
    }

    func saveToFile(data: Data, path: String) {
        let string = dataToPage437String(data: data)
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        try? string?.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: encoding)
    }

    func page437StringToData(string: String) -> Data? {
         return string.data(using: encoding)
    }

    private func dataToPage437String(data: Data) -> String? {
        return String(data: data, encoding: encoding)
    }
}
```

```swift
class EncryptionEngine {

    func encrypt(originalData: Data, keyData: Data) -> Data {
        var encryptedData = [UInt8]()

        for (index, byte) in originalData.enumerated() {
            let indexInCurrentBlock = index % keyData.count
            let row = Int(byte)
            let column = Int(keyData[indexInCurrentBlock])
            //for pure Vigenère cipher modifier should be 0
            let modifier = index + 1
            let encryptedCharacter = UInt8((row + column + modifier) % 256)
            encryptedData.append(encryptedCharacter)
        }

        return Data(encryptedData)
    }
}
```

```swift
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        let encryptionEngine = EncryptionEngine()
        let originalData = fileManager.loadFromFile(path: "/Path/test2.txt")
        guard let keyData = fileManager.page437StringToData(string: "keyToEncryptTakenFromTextField") else { return }
        let encryptedData = encryptionEngine.encrypt(originalData: originalData, keyData: keyData)
        fileManager.saveToFile(data: encryptedData, path: "/Path/test_enc.txt")
```

Comment: The function `saveToFile` can be simplified. It converts binary data to a string and the back to binary data using the same encoding. There is no need to go via a string.

Comment: Can you show me a snippet on how to save `Data` object directly to a file as a binary data?

Comment: You can reduce the entire function to `data.write(to: path)`.

Comment: which makes wrapping it in a separate method completely redundant. Awesome :D Thanks for the tip. You're 300% right!