# What is the correct process of encoding a non-Latin string and convert it to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, thermal-printer

I'm trying to print Simplified Chinese string using **Fujitsu FP-2100** thermal printer but the result doesn't match the original input.

Fujitsu iOS SDK(Obj-C) doesn't support Unicode and only supports **BIG5** code and **GB** code encoding. No mention of specific variants.

A method provided by the SDK requires the non-Latin string to be encoded and be passed to the thermal printer as `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` for printing.

To check if I've encoded it correctly, the string was, first, converted to Data using Big5 encoding and later converted back to string. And it was printed on console correctly.

However, I suppose something went wrong somewhere when I tried to convert it to `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`.

SDK method: `printer.printText(bytetext: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>!>, length: Int32)`

**Example code provided by their support (untested by them):**

```
NSString *strText = @"中国語...\n";

NSData *data = [strText dataUsingEncoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSString(kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseSimplif)allowLossyConversion:YES];

int length = [data length];
Byte *byteData= (Byte*)malloc(length);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], length);
nRtn = [mPrint PrintText:byteData length:length];
free(byteData);
```

**Here's what I did:**

Encoding reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064027/3476380

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.big5
let nsEnc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
let big5encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: nsEnc)
```

**1. First way :** Result printed by thermal printer was `ñH`

```
let str = "人"
if var data = str.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(big5encoding.rawValue))), allowLossyConversion: true) {
   var buf: [UInt8] = [UInt8]()
   buf.append(contentsOf: data)
   /* Initialization of UnsafeMutablePointer instance */
   var uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: buf.count)
   uint8Pointer.initialize(from: &buf, count: buf.count)

   self.printerController?.printText(uint8Pointer, length: Int32(buf.count))
}
```

**2. Second way :** Result printed by thermal printer was something like `『`

```
let str = "人"
if var data = str.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(big5encoding.rawValue))), allowLossyConversion: true) {
   var buf: [UInt8] = [UInt8]()
   buf.append(contentsOf: data)
   /* Initialization of UnsafeMutablePointer instance */
   var uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity:data.count)
   data.copyBytes(to: uint8Pointer, count:  data.count)

   self.printerController?.printText(uint8Pointer, length: Int32(buf.count))
}
```

By doing `print("Data: \(data as NSData)")` , result printed on console was `Data: {length = 2, bytes = 0xa448}` where the bytes corresponds to "人" correctly.

**Big5 code table**
http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tblbig.php?page=0

As I'm new to this process, any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have set up the driver with the right character set? It looks as if it is using other character set than Big-5.

Comment: Your Objective-C sample code uses the `kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseSimplif` encoding, that would be `CFStringEncodings.dosChineseSimplif` in Swift, not `CFStringEncodings.big5`.

Comment: @OOPer driver as in printer's driver? We are connecting the thermal printer via LAN. No drivers needed other than importing its SDK into the project.

Comment: @MartinR Correct but I was requested to replace ``kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseSimplif`` with the relevant supported encoding.

Comment: @Angeline: Both your methods convert the string "人" to the bytes `0xA4, 0x48` which is the correct Big 5 encoding. Your method of creating the pointer is far too complicated, but produces the correct result. If the printer output is wrong then the  encoding is wrong or problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I mean the SDK. Check the SDK documentation how you can set character encoding.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for confirming the encoded Big5 bytes and pointer created are producing the correct result. Issue could be the printer is expecting one of the Big5's encoding variant instead of just Big5. Tricky tricky.